# Convert Decimal value to Hours & Minutes; Also subtract two Hours/Minutes value from the another

Tags: c#

I have two decimal text boxes on the ASP.Net page:

```
Balance: 200.00 (200 Hrs and 00 Minutes)
TextBox1 = 75.30 (75 Hrs and 30 Minutes)
(After entering the value in TextBox1; the function should calculate the difference between Balance - TextBox1)
TextBox2:  (based on 60 min per hour) = 124.30 (124 Hrs and 30 minutes)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) to calculate the difference between the two values, you will have to pass in the hours and minutes separately though. In general I would avoid representing a time span as a decimal value, more commonly you see a colon as separator, i.e. 4:30.

```
//parse hours and minutes from textbox input

TimeSpan t1 = new TimeSpan(hours1, minutes1, 0);
TimeSpan t2 = new TimeSpan(hours2, minutes2, 0);

int deltaHours = (t1 - t2).Hours;
int deltaMinutes = (t1 - t2).Minutes;
```

Answer (score 1):

The [System.TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) struct provides functions for parsing and converting times. It will also let you perform arithmetic on time values.